# Display image while hiding URL

Tags: php

Relatively new to PHP, and I need to be able to do something. Hopefully it is actually possible :)

Basically, I have the functions to make a URL unique to the associated client when they login. The URL pulls up a javascript... thing.. it's difficult to explain. The object displays just fine in an Iframe, but I want to prevent the client from being able to see the variables attached to this.

Example: site.com/example.php?secret=variable

Advice on how to include the iframe without exposing that URL?

Comment: I didn't understand the relevance between the title and the question. And in short, what is browser based you cannot hide/make secret a variable.

Comment: Ask the variables from the iFrame app and run over HTTPS.
I can't think of any other solution :)

Comment: Despite breaking usability, everything will be perfectly viewable by analyzing frame HTML source / HTTP requests - every browser provide such features.

Answer (score 0):

if you want $_GET variables more or less 'hidden' in iframe src-field, i would suggest to use somekind of crypt to hide variables in it.

for example, if you wanted to include `section_id=1234` var=value pair in the iframe url ( example.php?section_id=1234 ) you could use

```
<iframe src="example.php?v=c2VjdGlvbl9pZD0xMjM0Cg==" >
```

now what you have to do is `base64_decode()` and `parse_url()` $_GET['v'] on example.php, so you get variables to work with.

Comment: That's just obfuscation, right? Though, I could just rename the variables so they have no relevance

Comment: you are correct. There just isn't a way to make html tag `<iframe src="url">` without showing 'url' in the source. with my suggestions you can hide it pretty well, but the string will always be there.

Comment: IF the secret is a number, would I be able to put it through some crazy arithmetic first and then reverse it on the other side (example.php). I would think that would be more effective than base64?

Comment: sure you could. If you feel base64 is not enough ( since it can be decrypted easily), you could use md5() with own salt to crypt the url string. This would give you advantage of using any variables in url string instead of using only one numeric value.